# Doubt about acceleration of mass on spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring

I do not remember when, but a while a ago I was told that for a spring with stiffness $k$ and a mass $m$, the equation $-kx = ma$ never holds. (assume a horizontal spring)

So if I was given a problem like this:

> You pull a mass $m$ attached to a spring with stiffness $k$ to the right of the equilibrium point $x = 5\text{ m}$ of the spring and you let it go, what is the acceleration of the mass?

Then is this question meaningless (or any other that is similar)? I forgot what the real question is like, but I have seem such a method was used to tackle these problems? As such an attempt to write $-kx = ma$?

Could someone please jog my memory? I realize I am asking you guys to 'read my mind', but please bear with me.

Comment: I'll point out that many equations in physics are meant to provide models that provide highly accurate descriptions of what experiments show, although strictly speaking they "never hold" exactly, since there are always additional complications that weren't addressed in the model. For most purposes, using the $-kx = ma$ equation would work just fine to answer the question you've posed.

Answer (score 2):

The spring "with mass" has two possible complications: it's affected by gravity, and it may have a non-negligible kinetic energy (inertia).

You say the spring is positioned horizontally - hence the gravity effect is irrelevant.

As long as you consider only static problems - the kinetic energy is irrelevant as well, and your spring behaves exactly as "massless". The same holds also for the problems with constant velocities (because what matters is not the energy, but its change).

However there will be inevitable effects in problems with accelerations. Again, if you're talking about constant accelerations (such as sliding blocks and etc.) - then the spring would probably deform non-uniformly, but remain "static" in its shape. This may be solved relatively simply. However if accelerations are not constants - you'll get a non-trivial dynamics.

Comment: There's also the complication that if a given string is stretched too far (beyond what is sometimes called a yield point), it will become distorted and no longer obey the Hooke's law relation.

Comment: @kleingordon: of course. Real-world spring have a so-called "elastic" range

Answer (score 0):

Well, the spring force is not the same everywhere. It is a function of $x$, so the value of force will be different for different $x$.

The acceleration at the amplitude position is maximum and the velocity is $0$.

The acceleration at the mean position is $0$ and the velocity is maximum.

$F = -kx$

$ma = -kx$

$a = -\omega^2x$

As we know that the movement of a block attached to a spring on a smooth plane is a case of simple harmonic motion,

$x = Asin(\omega t + \phi)$

$\frac{dx}{dt} = v = \omega$Acos($\omega$t + $\phi$)

$\frac{dv}{dt} = a = -\omega^2$Asin($\omega$t + $\phi$)

Therefore,  a = -$\omega^2$x

You have to use these equations to find the value of displacement, velocity and acceleration at the desired time. The phase constant $\phi$ tells us from where the motion begins. If it begins from the mean position $\phi = 0$  and if it begins from the amplitude position then  $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Please use the mathjax feature to format mathematical expressions. You can find a tutorial at [Mathjax Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You seem to be using mathjax to add Unicode symbols only. You should use it for entire mathematical expressions.

Comment: What you're saying isn't wrong, but it doesn't really address the problem he was having.  Acceleration is still purely due to how  stretched the spring is (in this linear model ignoring spring mass, friction losses, etc), you're just describing the full periodic motion.  At any point during this you could still use $ma = -kx$ to find a.  If the question wanted $a(t)$ it likely would have asked for it.